# Cannot read property CSS undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out why the code I'm currently working on produces an error

> Cannot read property css underfined.

Currently using `jQuery 3.3.1`. Not sure if the `.css` is deprecated. Can't seem to find a workaround it

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  var Slider = {
    init: function() {
      this.$sliderBanner = $('.slider-banner');
      this.$sliderItemsWrapper = $('.slider-items', this.$sliderBanner);
      this.$slides = $('.slides', this.$sliderItemsWrapper);
      this.$sliderButtons = $('.arrow', this.$sliderBanner);
      this.slideCount = $('.slides', this.$sliderItemsWrapper).length;

      this.sliderBannerWidth = $(this.$sliderBanner).width();
      this.$setSliderWrapperWidth = $(this.$sliderItemsWrapper).width(this.sliderBannerWidth * this.slideCount);

      this.$slides.width(this.sliderBannerWidth);
      this.bindButtons();

      // $('.-next').on('click', function() {
      //     console.log('test');
      // })
    },

    bindButtons: function() {
      var position = 0;

      $('.arrow.-next').on('click', function() {
        // console.log('slide next');
        var that = this;

        position++;
        if (position == -1) {
          position = that.slideCount - 1;
        }
        console.log('test');
        that.$sliderItemsWrapper.css('left', -(that.sliderBannerWidth * position));
      });
    }
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    Slider.init();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="slider-banner">
  <a href="#" class="arrow -prev">prev</a>
  <a href="#" class="arrow -next">next</a>
  <div class="slider-items">
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-detail">
    <h2 class="preamble-heading" data-preamble="Test Preamble">Sample Page</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.css` is not deprecated, it's likely that `$sliderItemsWrapper` is not returning a valid HTML element

Comment: That's a strange property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `var that = this;` outside of the click function.

```js
(function($) {
  'use strict';

  var Slider = {

    init: function() {

      this.$sliderBanner = $('.slider-banner');
      this.$sliderItemsWrapper = $('.slider-items', this.$sliderBanner);
      this.$slides = $('.slides', this.$sliderItemsWrapper);
      this.$sliderButtons = $('.arrow', this.$sliderBanner);
      this.slideCount = $('.slides', this.$sliderItemsWrapper).length;

      this.sliderBannerWidth = $(this.$sliderBanner).width();
      this.$setSliderWrapperWidth = $(this.$sliderItemsWrapper).width(this.sliderBannerWidth * this.slideCount);

      this.$slides.width(this.sliderBannerWidth);
      this.bindButtons();

      // $('.-next').on('click', function() {
      //     console.log('test');
      // })

    },

    bindButtons: function() {
      var position = 0;
      var that = this;
      $('.arrow.-next').on('click', function() {
        // console.log('slide next');


        position++;
        if (position == -1) {
          position = that.slideCount - 1;
        }
        console.log('test');
        that.$sliderItemsWrapper.css('left', -(that.sliderBannerWidth * position));

      });

    }

  };

  $(document).ready(function() {

    Slider.init();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-banner">
  <a href="#" class="arrow -prev">prev</a>
  <a href="#" class="arrow -next">next</a>
  <div class="slider-items">

    <div class="slides">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slides">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slides">
      <div class="image" style="background-image:url(images/danny-howe-422500-unsplash.jpg)">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="banner-detail">
    <h2 class="preamble-heading" data-preamble="Test Preamble">Sample Page</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```